# Wiring a prototype in blueprint

Tags: osgi, blueprint-osgi

Like Spring,  blueprint supports the prototype scope. But unlike Spring I can't see any documentation about how to use it.

In Spring you can ask the context to give you a new bean, what's the equivalent in the Blueprint world?

Answer (score 4):

BlueprintContainer.getComponentInstance() does exactly what you are looking for.

[osgi documentation:](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r5/enterprise/org/osgi/service/blueprint/container/BlueprintContainer.html)

> A Blueprint Container represents the managed state of a Blueprint
>   bundle. A Blueprint Container provides access to all managed
>   components. These are the beans, services, and service references. A
>   Blueprint Container can be obtained by injecting the predefined
>   "blueprintContainer" component id.

*Example*

**blueprint.xml:**

```
<!-- blueprintContainer is predefined component here -->
<bean id="myService" class="myPackage.MyService">
   <property name="container" ref="blueprintContainer"/>
</bean>
<!-- prototype which can be created from myService -->
<bean id="myPrototype" class="myPackage.MyPrototype" scope="prototype"/>
```

**MyService.java:**

```
// ...
// create new instance
MyPrototype myPrototype = 
     (MyPrototype) container.getComponentInstance("myPrototype");
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<!-- BlueprintContainer from Apache Aries-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.aries.blueprint</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.aries.blueprint.core</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If a bean is of scope prototype then a new instance of the bean is created each time the bean is injected somewhere. Therefore each client that gets a bean of scope prototype injected gets a new instance of the bean.

Comment: The bean would not be injected anywhere. The bean would be a stateful method object that would have references to other singletons. Therefore a factory would be required to create this fully wired with its own dependencies.

The object itself would a local variable in a service method - ie a delegate instance that implements the given task.