# Using a Service Factory to create an instance of an object that's wired in Blueprint XML

Tags: java, spring, osgi, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

I have a complex object that's wired together in a Blueprint XML config.

```
<bean id=”complexObject”>
        <property name=”subObject1” ref=”subObject1ref” />
        <property name=”subObject2” ref=”subObject2ref” />
   ...
</bean>
```

I expose like this:

```
<service ref=“complexObject“ interface=“org.service.IComplexObject“ />
```

It's consumed like this:

```
<reference id=“ref_complexObject“ interface=“org.service.IComplexObject“ />
```

Problem is: It's kinda Singleton, but what I need is always a new instance.

I came across "Service Factory" as described in chapter 5.6 of the OSGi Core Spec. Problem with a Factory is, that I would have to do all the wiring, that's done in Blueprint/Spring at the moment, in Java code again, no?

Is there a way that this Factory can return a new instance of my complexObject that's wired together in the Blueprint XML?

Comment: look at your question 1 hour ago. What you need is called prototype scope, and your question link an answer for this kind of thing

Comment: I also found this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384659/wiring-a-prototype-in-blueprint. The problem I have with this: I don't think I can access the container (<property name="container" ref="blueprintContainer"/>) in my Factory class (see chapter 5.6 of the OSGi Core Spec for Service Factory"...  implements ServiceFactory").